# Does the newly found orientation of Sgr A* match the theory that the Fermi bubbles might have been caused by jets?

Tags: event-horizon-telescope, sagittarius-a

The EHT just announced their great findings about Sgr A*, amongst other cool things they found that we look towards the black hole face on which means that if there is a jet it approximately looks into our direction.

Does this match one of the theories for Fermi bubbles, that they might have formed from the jets of Sgr A* or does the new information about the orientation rules this out?

Comment: Are we looking towards it or are we seeing a distorted image like in this image from NASA https://www.sciencealert.com/this-new-nasa-visualisation-of-a-black-hole-is-so-beautiful-we-could-cry

Comment: In https://doi.org/10.3847/2041-8213/ac6674 they say high inclination models fail, so looking towards us is probable.

Comment: From that paper "All edge-on (high inclination) models fail the combined set of EHT-only constraints..."  so high inclination in this case means edge-on.  Well I've learned something new today!  Thanks for that, and for linking to that paper.

Answer (score 3):

The video

discusses exactly this question around the 15 minute mark. The newly published results seem to favour an inclination between the spin axis of Sgr A* and the Fermi bubbles of about 60°. Some possible implications of this mismatch:

- Sgr A* was previously aligned with the Fermi bubbles, but changed orientation since then. For example due to a merger with another galaxy.
- Fermi bubbles might have been caused by some spherical phenomenon, but we only see them in the less dense parts outside of the galactic disc.
- Fermi bubbles might have some other origin.